# Cannot get path of picture from Uri which returned by Google Drive App and Downloads in onActivityResult()

Tags: android, android-file, android-fileprovider

What I'm trying to do in my application is to let the user choose a picture. As recommended in the most blogs, I delegate this functionality to the apps installed on devices. I throw a intent with these properties:

```
Intent pickPhotoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
pickPhotoIntent.setType("image/*");
pickPhotoIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
pickPhotoIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
```

with mentioned intent user can pick photo from these application in Sony Xperia XZ with Oreo Android version:

[image]

the Uri which receive in `onActivityResult()` ,

1) if user pick photo from Google Drive is like `"content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3DVmocHGi0P0XS_iMZxaRt3ofmo%0A"`

2) if user pick photo from Download is like `"content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FBabies%2FCR.gif"`

3) if user pick photo from other apps is like `"content://media/external/images/media/132411"`

I want to know how I can extract the path of selected picture and get content from first and second Uri.

I use this method for other Uri (third Uri) and it works.

```
public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri uri) {

    String filePath = "";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && uri.getHost().contains("com.android.providers.media")) {
        // Image pick from recent

        String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

        // Split at colon, use second item in the array
        String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

        String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        // where id is equal to
        String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return filePath;
    } else {
        // image pick from gallery
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                return cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, You are right. I got the solution. 
Thank you!